# Helm for loop list

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I wanted to use one deployment file and value file to create charts for multiple services.

My value file has the values of all the service, that has to be used one deployment file.

below is my deployment file content

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.PA.name }}-deployment
  labels:
    app: {{ .Values.PA.name }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.PA.replicas }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Values.PA.name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .Values.PA.name }}
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: {{ .Values.PA.name }}
        image: {{ .Values.PA.image }}:{{ .Values.PA.tag }}
        ports:
        - containerPort: {{ .Values.PA.port }}
```

Below is my values file

```
PA:
    name: povisioning_adapter
    replicas: 1
    env: dev
    image: provisioning_adapter
    tag: master
    port: 8001

    service:
        protocol: TCP  
        port: 8001
        targetPort: 8001
        nodePort: 30100
  
SA:
    name: service_adapter
    replicas: 1
    env: dev
    image: service_adapter
    tag: master
    port: 8002

    service:
        protocol: TCP  
        port: 8002
        targetPort: 8002
        nodePort: 30200
```

Now I want to iterate through PA, SA values, etc. inside my deployment file.
How to declare list [PA,SA,..] and for loop through it inside deployment file?

Comment: I'm a little more used to seeing a style of Helm chart where the `values.yaml` file is just the values the end user could configure.  The per-service `name:` and `port:` would probably never ever change, for example, and the `env:` is probably shared across all of the services.  This might require copying the overall structure of the Deployment into multiple files, but it may make it easier to use the final Helm chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap this in a `range` loop:

```yaml
{{- range list .Values.PA .Values.SA -}}
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .name }}-deployment
...
{{ end -}}
```

If you need to refer to the top-level `.Values`, in this setup you'd need to "escape" the `range` loop's scoping by explicitly referring to the top-level value `$`.  You also might need this in a template parameter.

```yaml
metadata:
  labels:
    name: {{ .name }}
{{ include "myapp.labels" $ | indent 4 }}
{{/*                      ^          */}}
```

You could do something similar breaking this out into a helper template that produced one of the Kubernetes objects.  You may be able to restructure this to use the name of the component rather than its specific settings; where you currently have `.Values.PA.name`, if you have the top-level `$.Values` object and you know the name, then `index $.Values "PA" "name"` is equivalent, and any of those parts can be replaced by variables.